# Каким образом объединить таблицы в одну

Tags: sql

Есть 2 несвязанные таблицы с первичными ключами data.

```
Income(point, date, inc)
Outcome(point, date, out)
```

Как мне получить вот такую результирующую таблицу, чтобы `NULL` было там где такой столбец вообще отсутствует?

```
point   date        inc         out
1      2001-03-14   NULL        15348.0000
3      2001-03-22   15000.0000  NULL
```

Comment: По какому полю строки таблиц должны объединятся? point?

Comment: @Anna, вы давали обязательство выполнять правила сайта www.sql-ex.ru

Comment: Хм, а просто через `UNION ALL` нельзя? Условие не до конца понятно. Могут быть на выходе строчки, в которых будет и `inc` и `out`?

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko частично обсуждалось здесь: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868

Comment: @Nofate, мне кажется, что просто нужна добрая воля модераторов, чтобы удалять подобные вопросы.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko модераторы не действуют по собственной воле, они ограничены правилами, которые вырабатывает сообщество.

Comment: @Nofate, кто, как не модератор, может повлиять на сообщество. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q.point, q.date, t1.inc, t2.out
FROM (SELECT point, date FROM Income
      UNION
      SELECT point, date FROM Outcome
     ) q
LEFT JOIN Income t1  ON t1.point=q.point AND t1.date=q.date
LEFT JOIN Outcome t2 ON t2.point=q.point AND t2.date=q.date
```

Или, если диалект позволяет

```
SELECT COALESCE (t1.point, t2.point) point, COALESCE (t1.date, t2.date) date, t1.inc, t2.out
FROM Income t1 
FULL JOIN Outcome t2 ON t1.point=t2.point AND t1.date=t2.date
```